# Can't boot into an operating system

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I Dual booted Ubuntu with Windows 7 today. Windows 7 first then Ubuntu.

And now when my computer starts it doesn't asks what operating system to boot. It just sits there doing nothing.
I was able to boot into Windows 7 by pressing F8 and choosing the **Start Windows normally** option.

Here are some things that you might need to know:

1. I used a USB stick to install Ubuntu
2. I used a program called Une-boot-in
3. I gave Ubunutu 30GB of free space

Comment: Need some more info: Do you have multiple hard drives or just one? Please try this: Boot into your USB stick and select try. Then open a program called gparted and take a picture of what your partition table looks like. If you have multiple hard drives do this for each of them (select from menu in top right in gparted)

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot Ubuntu from your USB stick. When it reaches to the point to ask whether you want to install Ubuntu or try it choose the option which says **`Try Ubuntu`**. Once the desktop shows up open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or by searching Terminal through the *Dash*. When you open the terminal type the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair    
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list   
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Then open *Boot-Repair*

Once you open it press the button which says:

```
Recommended repair (repair most frequent problems)
```

Please reply with a comment if this worked for you or not. If not please explain again exactly what happens when you are trying to boot to an OS.